# MySQL deadlocks with stored procedure generating UID

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, innodb, deadlock

I have a stored procedure generating UID's from a "ticket" table, but under load I'm getting lots of deadlocks. I'm calling this procedure many times from multiple concurrent connections whenever my task needs a new UID.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE a_uid BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT uid INTO a_uid FROM uid_data FOR UPDATE; # Lock
    INSERT INTO uid_data (stub) VALUES ('a') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uid=uid+1;
    SELECT a_uid+1 AS `uid`;
    COMMIT;
END
```

I did consider using:

```
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO uid_data (stub) VALUES ('a');
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

However I wasn't sure if that would be safe with concurrent connections as there's no locking, unlike the first procedure with the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Here's the table:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE uid_data;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stub  | char(1)             | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've setup for read-committed transaction isolation:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tx_isolation';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| tx_isolation  | READ-COMMITTED  |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

Here's what I'm getting back from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

```
...
... dozens and dozens of the following record locks...

Record lock, heap no 1046 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 61; asc a;;
 1: len 8; hex 00000000000335f2; asc       5 ;;

Record lock, heap no 1047 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 61; asc a;;
 1: len 8; hex 00000000000335f1; asc       5 ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 4 n bits 1120 index `stub` of table `my_db`.`uid_data` trx id 13AA89 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 583 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 61; asc a;;
 1: len 8; hex 00000000000334a8; asc       4 ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

I'd be grateful if someone could explain what's happening and how they can be avoided.

Comment: For information: the deadlock occurs even when using this simple sequence: `START TRANSACTION; SELECT uid FROM uid_data FOR UPDATE; UPDATE uid_data SET uid = uid +1 [[possible deadlock here]] ; COMMIT;` (therefore it has nothing to do with the `ON DUPLICATE` clause). However, no deadlock occurs with an isolation level of `REPEATABLE READ;`. I still don't know what to conclude from this point.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets
(
    uid serial
)
```

Then to get the next uid:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tickets VALUES (NULL);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

uid serial is equivalent to

```
uid BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
```

You shouldn't experience any deadlocks with this approach and can throw as many connections at it as you like.

Comment: I should add for clarity, that the LAST_INSERT_ID() is scope restricted - e.g. if 1000 of these queries are running simultaneously there is never any risk of getting the wrong number for a different connection.

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock occurs in this scenario:

Transaction 1 : requests a lock (`SELECT...FOR UPDATE`) and acquires it

Transaction 2 : requests a lock (`SELECT...FOR UPDATE`) and must wait

Transaction 1 : tries to insert, hits a duplicate, therefore updates (`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`) => deadlock

<strike>I am not too sure about the reason, I suspect it has something to do with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. I'm still investigating and will come back if I find out.</strike>

[Edit] A deadlock occurs even with:

```
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT uid FROM uid_data FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE uid_data SET uid = uid +1; -- here, a deadlock would be detected in a blocked, concurrent connection
    COMMIT;
END
```

What about this:

```sql
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;    
    UPDATE uid_data SET uid = uid +1;
    SELECT uid FROM uid_data;
    COMMIT;
END
```

You could drop your `stub` colum altogether. The only drawback is that you must initialise your uid_data with one row.

Comment: Does that revised stored procedure handle concurrency with any kind of locking?

Comment: @Sencha Yes, `UPDATE`is atomic, and it also locks the row(s) until the end of the transaction. However, I am still very curious about the reason of the dead lock in your original sequence (see also my comments to your question).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
UPDATE uid_data SET uid = LAST_INSERT_ID(uid+1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

on a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `uid_data` (
    `uid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This is thread safe and will not lock the table if it is MyISAM (except during the actual update statement).