# Spring batch MySql Sequence "Could not obtain last_insert_id()" reguarding engine type

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch 3.0.5. The same question regarding engine type for the MySql sequence tables.
Almost the same question as [spring-batch-storage-engine-as-myisam-than-innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857874/spring-batch-storage-engine-as-myisam-than-innodb). However I am getting errors (using ENGINE = InnoDB) such as

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain last_insert_id(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
```

After looking around I found there is a contradiction between what Spring Batch is doing and what the document says on [MySQLMaxValueIncrementer](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/support/incrementer/MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.html)

> The sequence is kept in a table; there should be one sequence table per table that needs an auto-generated key. The table type of the sequence table should be MyISAM so the sequences are allocated without regard to any transactions that might be in progress.

In order to keep using InnoDB for the sequence tables to support GTID replication, it seems like we have to implement our own strategy like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970600/migrating-spring-batch-myisam-sequence-tables-to-innodb).

My question would be if Spring Batch want to be consistent, why doesn't Spring Batch provide a built-in way or an alternative to the default MySQLMaxValueIncrementer?

Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058816/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-sequence-table-in-mysql) will give you a idea about your queries.

If you are using MySQL DB, then Sequence table should be in `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` You can have `innodb` also. But MyISAM engine has a built in to increment with different values according to your specific column.